# Using Pontryagin-Thom theorem to compute $\pi_{n+1}(S^n)$ for low values of $n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

In Dan Freed's [notes](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture2.pdf), he asks us to compute $\pi_2(S^1), \pi_3(S^2), \pi_4(S^3)$ (See Exercise 1.50) using Pontryagin-Thom theorem. [Note: In the notes there is a typo. Freed refers to Hopf degree theorem for this exercise.]

How do we solve this exercise?

---

**My thoughts:** We have to classify framed 1-manifolds in $S^{n+1}$ upto cobordisms. Essentially we have to classify a collection of framed circles (upto cobordism).

The pair of pants bordism will show that a collection of framed circles (with same orientation) are cobordant to a single framed circle with a particular orientation.

By a bent cylinder, we can show that two framed circles with opposite orientations are cobordant to the empty manifold.

So to solve the problem I have to answer:

> Are two framed circles cobordant?

I don't know how to answer this question and I am not sure if my reasoning is right.

Comment: I suspect that in Freed's notes, he meant to reference Theorem 2.35 instead.

Comment: Ok thanks. That means I have to use Pontryagin-Thom to solve the problem. In this case, I have to classify 1-dim manifolds, i.e. framed circles in $S^{n+1}$ upto cobordism.  A framed circle has a trivial normal bundle. So is it a loop in $SO(n)$ ? How do I translate the cobordism condition?

Comment: well, the 1-dim manifold doesn't have to be connected.  And yes, you get a loop in $SO(n)$.  I am not sure what you mean in terms of the cobordism.

Comment: I wanted to know how to classify framed 1 manifolds upto cobordism.